# i want to test if different years is a leap year or not. I want to be able to type in several years and try of all them

Tags: r

```
leap_year<-function(years) {

if(years>=400 && years%%100==0 && years%%400==0                        
| years%%100!=0 && years%%4==0) {

print(TRUE) 

}  else  {

print(FALSE) }

}
```

Comment: If you want your function to accept multiple years, consider using `ifelse()` rather than `if() {} else {}`

Comment: also I would like the function to return it as a data.frame, I think I need years to be a text vector for that to work. but first of all I need to be able to try several years at once, which I don't seem to understand how to do, I appreciate every answer, I am a newbie

Comment: I think this is the function that you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/52067205 . Although you can simplify that by dropping `ifelse` completely.

Answer (score 1):

The `lubrdiate` library has the `leap_year` function, don't reinvent the wheel.

Try:

```
library(lubridate)    

leap_year<-function(years) {
print(all(leap_year(years)))
```